# Can i add a DKIM and SPF record on my main domain?

Tags: spf, dkim

My webserver is hosted on Amazon EC2, on free tier, on say example.com. As i'm only using a single elastic ip address, and i don't want to pay for another, i thought about setting up postfix on my webserver rather then setting it up on mail.example.com (which is probably a better idea).

Most documents talk about adding these records to a subdomain, but can i put it on my main domain as well (i.e. example.com). I currently set my SPF as a TXT on my main domain and it passes SPF checks. Can i do the same for DKIM?

I just generated a key on https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/dkimwizard/ and it shows the private and public key, and below selector record and policy record.

While i understand where i need to put my private (postfix) and public key (in the dns txt/mx record) but not sure where i should add my 2 generated records (selector and policy). Can i add them both as TXT records under my main domain rather then having to create a subdomain (i.e. mail.example.com) ?

Your Selector Record:

```
rsa._domainkey.example.com IN TXT

"k=rsa;p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAnfOc9CYLS2I2/mSaDbRoZyJzlHYrS5aSjU3U94FKDmGUkG7HqLUFWRx6TkZVQ5JpKoyTA25PUpBnzdu11945B66EbrZGAYb3YE7kCJ1BSNjaXajd4fzkFfYV06riJgWC83wBc9hoIoDzAZDNFV/HKstjy8Zd2H81HnvpVGnuKeAQsKIdIyazYwv85kHwh8tRm0si4I251VJ9dHByoMu+/e/s8ppBhvaH0Ss1YZr5B7q8PVeoy6V+l9JMPkKt+wsELTBBKVk7LLYdiis3bHXaYL0cfjPerqfwkyX2Hq2xdSUZ90zw7W6pvsoFDVe/1H45ZbqkLJ8klz8YLzwPAJj13wIDAQAB"
```

Your Policy Record:

```
_domainkey.example.com IN TXT "o=~"
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**No, you can't.** You must have exactly as said in all the documentation and tutorials, i.e.

```
selectorname._domainkey.example.com. IN TXT "k=ra;P=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIB...
```

Here, the `_domainkey` comes from DKIM specification ([RFC 6376, 7.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6376#section-7.5)) and `selectorname` is the selector ([3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6376#section-3.1)) for identifying multiple signing keys from each other. While the selector is user-defined and could be anything, it must be the same than used in the `s=` tag in the signature:

```
DKIM-Signature a=rsa-sha1; q=dns; d=example.com; i=user@example.com; s=selectorname; ...
```

This will cause searching for the public key from **DKIM Namespace** ([3.6.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6376#section-3.6.2.1)), which **is a subdomain**.

> All DKIM keys are stored in a subdomain named `_domainkey`.  Given
> a    `DKIM-Signature` field with a `d=` tag of `example.com` and an `s=`
> tag    of `foo.bar`, the DNS query will be for `foo.bar._domainkey.example.com`.

This is just defined this way and it just differs from the SPF records that are defined ([RFC 7208, 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-3)) to be *placed in the DNS tree at the owner name it pertains to, not in a subdomain under the owner name*.

---

The `_domainkey.example.com. IN TXT "o=~"` was originally designed for providing information on signing policy in [DKIM Sender Signing Policy Internet-Draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-allman-dkim-ssp-00#section-5), where `o=~` would specify that the entity signs some but not all mail, while `-` and `!` would be more strict and `.` for not sending mail at all.

This was never actually used, so **you don't need** `_domainkey.example.com IN TXT "o=~"` at all.

For the real-life substitute of `o=` you should orientate towards [DMARC](https://dmarc.org/).
Without DMARC it's not possible to tell whether a domain uses DKIM or not; you could only check if DKIM passes whenever it is present, but it doesn't cover messages without the signature header.

> A DMARC policy allows a sender to indicate that their messages are
> protected by SPF and/or DKIM, and tells a receiver what to do if
> neither of those authentication methods passes – such as junk or
> reject the message.

When implementing DMARC you should already have both SPF and DKIM working.

Comment: But i specified a selectorname (rsa). Your answer doesnt really tell me why i cannot use it without a subdomain. Could you elaborate? (and keep it simple please :-). I don't understand why i can't use it on a toplevel domain. My SPF record works on my toplevel domain. Surely more people then me combined both mail and http on the same server? And are you saying i should not use DKIM at all, but use DMARC instead?

Comment: alternatively if i have to use a subdomain, i suppose i could create a mail subdomain as an A record and point it to my domain.com ip address, as i have with my www. record. although i'd prefer if people didn't end up on my webserver when going to mail.domain.com

Comment: Of course you can use `rsa` as a selector name, it could be `yourmother`. I just had to change it in my example in order to distinguish it from other uses of `rsa`, because it's also also used in signature algorithm name (`a=rsa-sha1`).

Comment: DKIM records are all _text records_ (`TXT`), not _address mapping records_ (`A`). They are not resolving to any IP. Therefore, you are not creating any new subdomains, just adding the DKIM information in the standard (and only) way. I also clarified the DMARC part of my answer.

Comment: Thank you Esa. So why can't i add rsa._domainkey.example.com IN TXT as a TXT record to my main domain.com ? Why do i have to create a subdomain ? I added the SPF TXT to my main domain, and that seems to be working fine.

Comment: Because every system looks for it in `selector._domainkey.example.com.`, based on the DKIM specification, and non of them queries `@ TXT` in order to find it. SPF is a whole different standard and it MUST be there. It's just how they are specified. Just like pizza comes to your door and mail into your mailbox, not the opposite. (I actually like this analogy... and wish there was a spam filter for Jehovah's Witnesses.)

Comment: Lol i still dont understand it. selector can be anything right, it doesnt have any bearing with the subdomain. And why does the DKIM wizard let me make one for my main domain.com ?Anyway i'm sure you're right, so if i would not want to setup a new ip, but use my main one, how would i do it? I attached a picture, you'd do me a huge favor if you could help me out there.

Comment: ok i have to wait until i get home, i cant upload from where i am. Hope you're still there once i do. If not, thanks so far for your time.

Comment: The selector can be `s=anything`, but the public key data is always searched from corresponding `anything._domainkey.example.com. TXT` record. I don't know how I can say this more clear, but I tried to add a clarification that **DKIM Namespace is a subdomain**.

Comment: Likewise, is you'd set DKIM for `user@subdomain.example.com`, you would have `d=subdomain.example.com`, `s=some` and the DNS record would become `some._domainkey.subdomain.example.com. TXT`. Hope you are already figuring this out.

Comment: Hi Esa! I was hung up that they are not A records, but TXT records. So the protocols just need a TXT record defined. I kept the SPF record under my maindomain.com, and i added dkim and dmarc under my subdomains, and a mx record to boot. Thank you for your explanation, it sure helps.

Comment: Finally, but: exactly! Congrats!